# Low water pressure in a specific sink after turning off the supply lines

Tags: water, kitchens, sink, water-pressure

Water pressure is normal in my entire house, however, recently, I had to turn off the shutoff valves to a single sink.

Since I closed the shutoff valves and then opened them fully, the water pressure has been absolutely nonexistent even when I have the knobs opened fully. But here's the kicker: the pressure to the spray hose is absolutely normal. It's only the faucet that has low pressure.

This seems like a pretty basic fix that just escapes me.

Answer (score 2):

Many faucets have an aerator device and a wire mesh screen at the point where the water comes out. The piece is screwed on. If your faucet has something like this, remove it and check for debris. (Pay attention while disassembling: the order and direction of the parts matters with some designs.) The assembly uses a "normal" (right hand) thread, but often hard water deposits make it difficult to turn.

Comment: That's exactly what I going answer.